# populate a list / list of lists with no repeated data from a file

Tags: python, list

So I need to take a load of names from a file and create a list it currently works but the names should no repeat and I can figure this out I tried messing around with random.sample but as it is in a loop this becomes pointless.

```
  def open_cards(number_of_cards):
    cards = []
    txtfile="mytextfile.txt"
    file = open(txtfile).read().splitlines()
    for x in range (0, int(number_of_cards) * 2):
        listy = []
        xmen_name = random.choice(file)
        power = random.randint(0, 100)
        intelligence = random.randint(0, 50)
        weakness = random.randint(0, 10)
        spirit = random.randint(0, 10)
        listy.insert(0, xmen_name)
        listy.insert(1, power)
        listy.insert(2, intelligence)
        listy.insert(3, weakness)
        listy.insert(4, spirit)
        cards.append(listy)
    print("this is the card list prior to shuffle")
    print(cards)
```

Answer (score 0):

If en entry should not be reated this sounds like a job for a `dict`. So:

```
cards = {}
for x in range (0, int(number_of_cards) * 2):
    # code
    cards[xmen_name] = (power, intelligence, weakness, spirit)
```

I would say use a tuple, I don't think XMen stats should be modified :)

Comment: It is not a good solution as you probably won't have int(number_of_cards) * 2 cards at the end

Answer (score 0):

I would use [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html?highlight=shuffle#random.shuffle)

Shuffling names first, then iterate

(I don't get why you create number_of_cards * 2 cards and not just number_of_cards)

```
def open_cards(number_of_cards):
    cards = []
    txtfile="mytextfile.txt"
    with open(txtfile) as f:
        names = list(f)
    random.shuffle(names)
    for i in range(number_of_cards * 2):
        listy = []
        xmen_name = names[i]
        power = random.randint(0, 100)
        intelligence = random.randint(0, 50)
        weakness = random.randint(0, 10)
        spirit = random.randint(0, 10)
        listy.append(xmen_name)
        listy.append(power)
        listy.append(intelligence)
        listy.append(weakness)
        listy.append(spirit)
        cards.append(listy)
    print("this is the card list prior to shuffle")
    print(cards)
```

Comment: This does not work so for example it is a card game. the user selects how many cards they want for example 6 the code pulls 12 xmen names from the txt file and adds 1 to a new list then repeats creating the cards at the moment duplicates can be created which is bad.

Comment: Well you lost me there.

Comment: I think you doing the wrong way, you should create a card deck with unique xmens before the game starts.

Comment: Not really you create cards when user is picking cards from the deck. You should create cards before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to remove the duplicate values in `list`

```
Listy = [power, intelligence, weakness, spirit, weakness, power]
unique_listy = set(Listy)
print(unique_listy)
```

**Output**

```
{power, intelligence, weakness, spirit}
```

Comment: the code distributes the cards to the use so say 6 for player and 6 for cpu if I use this it would mean player had 5 and cpu 6 for example.

Comment: Why don't you make `file = open(txtfile).read().splitlines()` a "set" and then pick from that so u will have unique choice every time